# How to display events in fullcalendar with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Something's wrong with my code. The calendar displays fine and works fine. But events do not show. I believe it must have something to do with css? After searching hours in the css files and on SO, I need help. I use jquery and hardcoded events for testing.

**files**

```
<link href='css/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'/>
<script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

**html**

```
   <div id='calendar'></div>
```

**js**

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({

            editable:true,
               header:{
                left:'prev,next today',
                center:'title',
                right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
               },
               events: [
                   {
                     title: 'All Day Event',
                     start: '2019-11-01',

                   },
                   {
                     title: 'Long Event',
                     start: '2019-11-07',
                     end: '2019-11-10'
                   },
                   {
                     groupId: '999',
                     title: 'Repeating Event',
                     start: '2019-11-09T16:00:00'
                   },
                   {
                     groupId: '999',
                     title: 'Repeating Event',
                     start: '2019-11-16T16:00:00'
                   },
                   {
                     title: 'Conference',
                     start: '2019-11-11',
                     end: '2019-11-13'
                   },
                   {
                     title: 'Meeting',
                     start: '2019-11-12T10:30:00',
                     end: '2019-11-12T12:30:00'
                   },
                   {
                     title: 'Lunch',
                     start: '2019-11-12T12:00:00'
                   },
                   {
                     title: 'Meeting',
                     start: '2019-11-12T14:30:00'
                   },
                   {
                     title: 'Birthday Party',
                     start: '2019-11-13T07:00:00'
                   },
                   {
                     title: 'Click for Google',
                     url: 'http://google.com/',
                     start: '2019-11-28'
                   }
                 ]
        });
```

Comment: `events` should have the same structure. `groupId, title, start, end` in each case.

Comment: @Roy : thanks for contributing but it shouldn't matter at all. I just tested it for fun and nope.

Comment: @Roy actually groupId and end are optional. Only title and start are required. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object

Comment: Your events show up fine for me (using fullCalendar 3.10 - I assume from your code that you're using version 3). Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKwGrLr?editable=true&editors=001 . Not sure what your issue is. Just remember they all take place in November so you need to navigate to November before anything will show up! And if you've got any custom CSS in your page, or you've changed the fullCalendar CSS, remove that extra/changed CSS and use the standard fullCalendar CSS, and see if they show. That'll help you narrow it down to a more specific problem.